# simple Tab application in Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I am looking for example of simple Tab application without React functionality with one button, which can invoke task module with [Custom Form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/task-modules-tabs?tabs=teamsjs1%2Cteamsjs3) on click event by TeamsJs v2

Thanks

Comment: Please have look into this sample-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/app-task-module/csharp
Hope it is helpful!